# Pythonic way to regroup a pandas dataframe using max of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame that has been obtained by applying `df.groupby(['category', 'unit_quantity']).count()`

| category | unit_quantity | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| banana | 1EA | 5 |
| eggs | 100G | 22 |
|  | 100ML | 1 |
| full cream milk | 100G | 5 |
|  | 100ML | 1 |
|  | 1L | 38 |

Let's call this latter dataframe as `grouped`. I want to find a way to regroup using columns `unit_quantity` and `Count` it and get

| category | unit_quantity | Count | Most Frequent unit_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| banana | 1EA | 5 | 1EA |
| eggs | 100G | 22 | 100G |
|  | 100ML | 1 | 100G |
| full cream milk | 100G | 5 | 1L |
|  | 100ML | 1 | 1L |
|  | 1L | 38 | 1L |

Now, I tried to apply `grouped.groupby(level=1).max()` which gives me

| unit_quantity |  |
| --- | --- |
| 100G | 22 |
| 100ML | 1 |
| 1EA | 5 |
| 1L | 38 |

Now, because the indices of the latter and `grouped` do not coincide, I cannot join it using `.merge`. Does someone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: May be good to have the text data to be posted rather jpg/png which will be easy to reproduce and test for any further answers on this.

Comment: Oh weird... I didn't post any images. It should be only text.

Comment: Answer is correct? Are you sure?

Comment: OK, closed by dupe. Because accepting means need this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your DataFrame :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['banana', 'eggs', 'eggs', 'full cream milk', 'full cream milk', 'full cream milk'], 
...                    'unit_quantity': ['1EA', '100G', '100ML', '100G', '100ML', '1L'], 
...                    'Count': [5, 22, 1, 5, 1, 38],}, 
...                   index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) 
>>> df
    category    unit_quantity   Count
0   banana                1EA       5
1   eggs                 100G      22
2   eggs                100ML       1
3   full cream milk      100G       5
4   full cream milk     100ML       1
5   full cream milk        1L      38
```

You can use the `transform` method applied on `max` of the column `Count` in order to keep your `category` and `unit_quantity` values :

```py
>>> idx = df.groupby(['unit_quantity'])['Count'].transform(max) == df['Count']
>>> df[idx]
    category    unit_quantity   Count
0   banana                1EA       5
1   eggs                 100G      22
2   eggs                100ML       1
4   full cream milk     100ML       1
5   full cream milk        1L      38
```